# Iterating through dictionary values using a regex

Tags: python, zapier

In Zapier, my trigger is when an email is labeled and after 24 hours, if a "Reply to Email" does not exist, run Python to extract the Company Name with regex. After it's extracted, it searches a database for that company and updates the record.

The problem I'm having is iterating through a dictionary using a regex and returning the extracted company name. Can anyone please help?

```
output = {'Subject': input_data['Subject']}
import re

subject_line= 'Signed Renewal Docs: abc company, inc.'

pat = re.compile(r'((SIGNED )?(RENEWAL )?)+(DOCS){1}( |: )+(COMPANY 
NAME|PERSONS NAME)(, | )*((INC|Incorporated)|(CORP|Corporation)|(LLC|Limited Liability Company))?((DBA)( COMPANY NAME))?', re.I)
#there are a lot of company types this is supposed to account for

for key, value in output.items():
    if re.match(value,pat):
        return COMPANY NAME
    #this is supposed to return the company name
```

Comment: Can you provide some detail on the `output` data structure? You declare it as a list of dictionaries, but then treat it as a list of two-tuples. Perhaps you meant to declare it as a dict then iterate over its items (ie `for k, v in output.items(): ...`). And what is input data? Where in this structure does the company name actually lie?

Comment: With Zapier, the input_data dictionary is built-in and I only put in 1 input. The dictionary works like input_data = [{'string i put in': email subject line}]. So in a way the value from the pair is actually a variable.

Comment: Where to start... your `output` is defined as a `list` of a `dict` with a single key `'Subject'` with a single value from `input_data['Subject']`.  When you iterate through a `list` you cannot unpack it into a `key` and `value`.  And even if you could, you are still only working with one element only.  How exactly are you hoping to make use of the regex? When you say `#some func to iterate` did you have a function that wasn't posted or are you *asking us to code for you*?

Comment: Output is auto-generated as well. I'm a beginner and don't exactly know how it best fits.

Comment: Alright, I fixed the list/dictionary issue. Output is just a dictionary and I was confused for a second. I also hopefully made something to move this forward.

   for key, value in output.items():
    if re.match(value,pat):
        return COMPANY NAME